# What is better.. to have separate functions or combined functions in php?

Tags: php, performance, function

My question is basically is .. What is good practice for making a function in PHP?
Eg - if i have two options upvote and downvote. 
So one choice is making 2 seperate functions for upvote and downvote like -

```
function upvote($id,$user){
    //The upvote code goes here..
}
function downvote($id,$user){
    //The downvote code goes here..
}
```

another choice is combining the two functions and make them one using if-else 
eg :

```
function vote($id,$user,$vote){
    if( $vote == 'upvote' ){
        //The upvote code goes here..
    }
    else {
       // the downvote code goes here..
    }
}
```

So i wanted to know which of the two methods is a good practice and which can be more speedy ( Performance wise ).
PS - I am including my function file on top of Every page.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it and see which one will gain you a millisecond or two? :)

Comment: The first one requires 2 function definitions, but does not require an conditional branching operation when any of the functions is called. The second one requires only 1 function definition, but does require an conditional branching operation when called. Performance-related issues are strictly irrelevant here.

Comment: single function can be ok if you expect the function to be succinct. If you have many operations within each condition then it is better to split them up for readability and stability purposes. Strictly from a human standpoint that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think First choice can be good :

```
function upvote($id,$user){
  //The upvote code goes here..
}
function downvote($id,$user){
  //The downvote code goes here..
}
```

Because this can be flexible in terms of editing the code in future and as far as speed is concerned.. I dont think both will vary much :)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to separate them out.  A good goal is to have each function only perform one action.  It makes it much easier to debug in the future and it lends to much more readable code.  That principle is better explained here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: You are correct, but again, while both **upvoting** and **downvoting** can be both treated as a single action, but so can just **voting**, right?

Comment: Yeah, those two actions might not be distinct enough to require 2 different methods, but I think it's best to be as granular as you can within reason.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting code into seperate functions reduces its `toxicity` and is therefore recommended.

Or in other words: The bigger and more complex a function grows the more it will get difficult to read and also increases the potential of bugs.

Also if a piece of code can be separated into logical parts you should do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any gain in  making one function instead of two. It depends on what is
 inside the function :db calls, webservices call ecct.

One function could make sense if the functionality inside the two functions is the same and
the only thing that changes is the $vote parameter and you
don't want to repeat yourself, copy/paste code in different functions.

I always try to use the single responsability pattern so that  one function does only
 that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From the human's perspective you may think voting is an single action - just voting; 'cause in general you wouldn't say - I'm going to up-vote or down-vote someone ;). But in this case, and if you think object-oriented, you have a post witch can be down-voted or up-voted. Something like this

```
class post {

    var $votes = 0;

    // other staff

    function up-vote () {
       $this->votes = $this->votes++;
    }

    function down-vote () {
       $this->votes = $this->votes--;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class `post` has `two separate methods`. In terms of performance, the differences are minor.